# Windows 10 receiving constant keypress

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

About half the time when I power on my windows 10 PC it constantly receives a keypress. [keycode.info](https://keycode.info) shows code 177 (media back/previous) constantly being pressed. Rebooting seems to solve the issue. The issue does not show up randomly while using the PC. It only shows up upon cold boot and stays until I reboot the computer.

The issue persisted after changing both keyboard and mouse, and windows is receiving the keypresses even with no keyboard attached at all. It also does not happen with all the same peripherals connected to a different PC.

So how can I troubleshoot this? Is there any utility that can identify the source of a keypress (which device or software?)

Comment: Try booting with a bootable USB key (Windows 10 ISO from the Media Creation Link) and see if the keyboard does the same thing started this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to try following methods and check if it helps.

Go to `Power Options`, on the left select Choose `what the powwer button does`, disable `Turn on Fast Startup`

Please do let us know if it's work

Comment: That did solve it, thank you.